# Bios setting; AHCI or Intel Optane (Raid),which one should choose for 2 nvme ssd

Tags: bios, ahci

I install the two NVME ssd in my laptop. One is 256g, boot window, and another is 512g for keeping data. In my laptop, there are two options; AHCI and Intel optane (Raid). Which seeting should I choose for two NVME SSD?

Comment: “Which setting should I choose for two NVME SSD?” - You can’t RAID two SSDs which are different sizes, or you can but the RAID would be limited to the smaller drive, so it doesn’t make sense to do so. So do you want a RAID? Unless these are Intel SSDs it doesn’t make sense to enable Intel Optane.

Comment: Do you have Intel optane installed (hardware)?

Comment: @Ramhound: Mode RAID doesn't mean that one is obliged to create a RAID.

Comment: Why would one enable Intel Optane which essentially prevents dual booting Linux if not to use its functionality?

Comment: I don't have intel optane hardware. One is Samsung ssd and the other is Chinese ssd. I just want to know which option is suitable for my laptop, AHCI or Intel Optane. Because my bios give two options, AHCI and Intel optane.